# libvirt kvm qemu virtual machine - hard code domain-id?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, virsh

Is there a way to hard code the domain-id of a virtual machine kvm guest?

I tried adding an id attribute to the XML configuration via

```
virsh edit name
```

And I also tried to edit the XML directly stored in /etc/libvirt/qemu

Basically, I'd like all of my virtual machine domain-ids to stay the same forever and never change.  As new virtual machines are added, they should increment in id.  Is there a way to do this, or will an external program interfacing with the virtual machines be required to do so by a unique name for the virtual machine?

Comment: Huh? What ID are you referring to?

Comment: The domain-id as referred to:  https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Virtualization/chap-Virtualization-Managing_guests_with_virsh.html

Comment: That ID only refers to _running_ VMs and stopped VMs have no ID. If you need a unique identifier, use the UUID; that's what it's for.

Comment: Great, so it looks like you can manage a vm using the UUID, but how do you get a list of the name, id, and UUID?  virsh list --all only returns the ID, name, and state.  So, how is one to discover the UUID from making a generic list call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/virsh) is your friend.

The virsh sub-command `domuuid` will return the uuid of the provided domain-name or domian-id.

The sub-command `domid` returns the id when provided the domain-name or domain-uuid of a running machine.

The sub-command `domname` gives domain-name when provided with a domain-uuid or domain-id.

Note that the domid sub-command is only valid if a machine is running and that domain-id is similarly only available for a running machine.

Comment: Awesom ? Nah, I just read the documentation after using google.